# Android click on the button to go to another page?

Tags: java, android, button

I need to link the button with the page (not the main page) like when I click on the button to go to the page for example (location page)?

```
private void setupLocationPageButton() {

    Button LocationPageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationPage);
    LocationPageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i think you trying to do: is when you click on button it's change the MainActivity

---

```
Button LocationPageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationPage);
LocationPageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener({
     public void onClick(View _view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TheActivityTheclassNameYouWannGoTo.class);
     startActivity(i);
     }
}));
```

but first you have to creat activity and class inherit Activity like MainActivity

---

initialize the class in AndroidMainfest.xml

---

i hope this help you

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to open another activity this is what you are going to want to do.

In your xml file you are going to want something like this

```xml
...

<Button
android:id="@+id/activity_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
android:text="@string/text_of_button" />

...
```

Then in your activity you want

```
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fragment, each fragment contains a specific page, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for Android fragment.

Comment: Meh. This could be a comment. Include some relevant code, rather than a link that may or may not help him.

Comment: @ mike yaworski, just tried to give some tips, you are right, I'll try my best to help :)